# $N$ Independent Oscillators Entropy and Number of States

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, entropy, harmonic-oscillator

I have been working on building intuition and experience with solving problems related to the microcanonical ensemble, but I haven't been able to solve the following problem:

If you have $N$ independent oscillators, each having the same oscillation frequency $\omega$, given the energy $E=(N_E+\frac{N}{2})\hbar\omega$, find the number of states with energy E and calculate the entropy as a function of the energy.

**What I tried/thought:**

Since the oscillators don't interact and are said to have the same vibrational frequency, I don't see how the energy could be anything other than the sum of their vibrational energies, which would be a constant given that $\omega$ seem to be a constant. I'm also unsure how to interpret $N_E$, so I'm unable to move forward.

My gut tells me to do something like this to calculate the number of states,

$\frac{E}{N}=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{N_E}{N})\hbar\omega$

from which, if I'm reading incorrectly that all having the same vibrational frequency means **all** vibrating at the same frequency and instead that **if** they vibrate they vibrate at the same frequency, I would extract that the fraction of particles vibrating to produce a system with a certain energy E would be given by $\frac{N_E}{N}=\frac{E}{N}-\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$. The  term subtracted from $\frac{E}{N}$ would represent a ground energy for each atom. The number of states that would satisfy this would be $N\choose N_E$, though I don't think this reduces to a nice number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy levels of a system of $N$ independent oscillators, all with the same frequency $\omega$, have the form
$$
E(n_1,\dots,n_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N \hbar\omega\left(n_i+\frac12\right),
$$
where $n_i$ is the number of quanta of energy in $i$-th oscillator. Hence, in your formula,
$$
N_E = \sum_{i=1}^N n_i.
$$
From here it is straightforward to obtain, that the number of *different* states of the system of N oscillators with energy corresponding to the number $N_E$ is equal to
$$
\Gamma(N_E) = \sum_{n_1,\dots,n_N \geq 0} \Delta(n_1+\dots+n_N - N_E),
$$
where $\Delta(x) = 1$ if $x=0$ and $\Delta(x) = 0$ if $x\neq0$. A simple explicit formula for the $\Gamma(N_E)$ can be derived in different ways.

Comment: Thanks. Just to see if I understood $\Gamma(N_E)$, this is equivalent to the number of partitions of $N_E+N$ - not $N_E$ because $n_i$'s can be zero - into N parts, right?

Comment: @Fhoenix, I would rather say, that $\Gamma(N_E)$ is exactly the number of ways to write $N_E$ as a sum of $N$ nonnegative integers.

Comment: Why do you assume that every oscillator has only one fulled level of energy? Why don't we have to write sequence for every oscillator {0,1,0.0,1} ...

Comment: @AslanMonahov In this problem, the state of any of the oscillators is determined by only one number $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$. You are probably referring to _another_ problem in which particles, fermions or bosons, are distributed across the energy levels of the osacillator.

Comment: but harmonic oscillator also can have a superposition of different energy levels, not just one certain

Comment: @AslanMonahov Yes, it can. But this fact is irrelevant to the question discussed in this topic. Besides, systems in thermodynamic equilibrium are in stationary states.