# Why do we assume harmonic oscillator to have only one fulled level of energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

My question is related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/472947/325920) problem. There were considered only one $n_i$ level of energy for i-th oscillator, but I think we should write $\{n\}_i$ sequence of fulled levels for every oscillator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited problem is dealing with entropy and trying to derive the partition function of N particles, each of which is a HMO with the same $w$. So each particle is in its own energy state. That is, each particle has one energy state. When they interact, as they must to get some kind of equilibrium, they can exchange energy. Each will gain or lose an integer multiple of $\hbar w$, and finish up in some specific state.

That is, it is explicitly assumed in the statement of the problem that each HMO has a single energy given by the usual $\hbar w  (n + \frac{1}{2})$. It is not *always* assumed, but assumed for the purposes of the problem being solved.